# Addon tracking click on result Google not working?

Tags: firefox-addon, clicklistener

Thank you for your quick reply.
I want to track a link based on google search results.

It works in some cases as nomal but doesn't work on links that are google search results, eg https:// www.google.com.vn /?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+adwords.
I will try to reproduce problem step by step:
1. Install addon with handle event click following code.

```
function handleWindowClick(event) {
            var origEl = event.target;
            if(origEl.tagName == 'A') {
                // do some things with event link: origEl.toString();
                alert("Event Link: " + origEl.toString());
            } else if(origEl.parentNode.tagName == 'A') {   
                alert("Event Link: " + origEl.parentNode.toString());
            } else if(origEl.tagName == 'SPAN') {
                alert("Span  is clicked"); 
            }
    }

window.addEventListener('click', handleWindowClick, false);
```

1. Go to link https://www.google.com.vn/?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+adwords on the browser.
2. Click any link on search result, eg "Google AdWords – Online advertising by Google" link (http:// adwords. google.com).
   Expected result: 
   Alert message like "Link: adwords.google.com";
   But it doesn't alert any things. In the console log, it show a js error message like event is null".
   Please help me!!!

Comment: Can you provide more of your code, and more detail on the problem. Can you provide what is the function `handleWindowClick`.

Comment: ps: shame on the person voting to close your topic, just because you don't type english so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update based on your code you edited in:

```
 function handleWindowClick(event) {
            var origEl = event.target;
            if(origEl.tagName == 'A') {
                // do some things with event link: origEl.toString();
                alert("Event Link: " + origEl.toString());
            } else if(origEl.parentNode.tagName == 'A') {   
                alert("Event Link: " + origEl.parentNode.toString());
            } else if(origEl.tagName == 'SPAN') {
                alert("Span  is clicked"); 
            }
    }

window.addEventListener('click', handleWindowClick, false);
```

ps: shame on the person voting to close your topic, just because you don't type english so well.

Comment: Thanks you. I will try your code. I'm from VietNamese so english not good.

Comment: Hello. I try but not working and possibleLinks[i] is null. Addon description:
Go to this link https://www.google.com.vn/?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+adwords
If click on 1 link Addon will alert link and text click. Thanks

Comment: Ok I edited the topic with updated code. Try it out, it works for me.

Comment: Hi  Noitidart, I updated my question. Your code working in nomal case. With Result search Google it not working.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and share, his code works for me on all links.